# Spring boot websockets send data via RxJs Angular Websockets

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, websocket, rxjs

I am new to websockets and I am kinda struggling in writing real time websocket communication between Spring boot back-end and Angular frontend.
Use case is pretty simple, its about **item real time bidding**. So idea is there are some "rooms" for which we want to subscribe for new info.

My current angular websocket service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebSocketService {

  connections: Array<ConnectionForHighestBid>;
  RETRY_SECONDS = 10;

  constructor() {
  }

  connect(itemId: number): Observable<any> {
    return of('http://localhost:8090').pipe(
      map(apiUrl => apiUrl.replace(/^http/, 'ws') + '/ws-item/' + itemId + '/highest-bid'),
      switchMap(wsUrl => {
        const connection = this.connections.filter(c => c.itemId === itemId);

        // In case we already connected for given item id
        if (connection && connection.length === 1) {
          return connection[0].connection$;
        } else {
          const newConnection: ConnectionForHighestBid = {
            itemId,
            connection$: webSocket(wsUrl)
          };
          this.connections.push(newConnection);

          return newConnection.connection$;
        }
      }),
      retryWhen((errors) => errors.pipe(delay(this.RETRY_SECONDS)))
    );
  }
}

export interface ConnectionForHighestBid {
  itemId: number;
  connection$: WebSocketSubject<any>;
}
```

and inside component of one item I am doing following (this.itemId is id of item I want to subscribe for websocket communication:

```
this.webSockedService.connect(this.itemId).pipe(
  takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
).subscribe(data => {
  // Handle the newest data here (update price, add new bid item info, ...)
  console.log(data);
});
```

Backend is using Spring boot websockets and have following methods for now:

```
@MessageMapping("/ws-item/update/{itemId}")
@SendTo("/ws-item/{itemId}/highest-bid")
public ResponseEntity<ItemWsInfoResponse> getHighestBidDetail(@DestinationVariable("itemId") long itemId) {

    return new ResponseEntity<>(itemService.findHighestBidByItemId(itemId), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@MessageMapping("/ws-item/bid/{itemId}")
@SendTo("/ws-item/{itemId}/highest-bid")
public ResponseEntity<ItemWsInfoResponse> bid(@DestinationVariable("itemId") long itemId,
                                                              @RequestBody @NonNull @Valid ItemWsBidRequest request) {

    LocalDateTime currentTime =
            LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(System.currentTimeMillis()), ZoneId.systemDefault());

    Optional<ItemWsInfoResponse> bidOpt = itemService.bid(itemId, request, currentTime);

    return bidOpt
            .map(i -> new ResponseEntity<>(i, HttpStatus.OK))
            .orElseGet(() -> new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST));
}
```

In both cases, output is a POJO holding information about item and currently highest bid which will FE consume.
Where first method is to get current info. I am not really sure if I need that method. **Is is possible to perform this action on websocket connect**? Si If I successfully connect, I get this POJO.

And the second method is the bidding itself (there is no need to go deeper into it, method just do checks and creates bid and return current state in that POJO).

The configuration is like following

```
/**
 * Websocket configuration
 *
 * Request URL: /ws-item
 * Subscription URL: /ws-item/{itemId}
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/ws-item");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws-item").setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

The code seems to be OK (Or, at least I am getting "connected" to my backend websocket layer. **But I am not really sure how to perform that bid action from frontend.** I would like to send message to BE to bid on given item, BE would do some checking and in case of success, it would send message to that "general" pool I am subscribing now where I can handle data (update item price, add new row for new bid, check if logged user is currently winning etc).

So the question is: **How can I perform that bid action from FE on given connection** (the data send to that bid BE method can be dummy and static for now, fill JSON dynamically is the smallest problem here)? And is it possible to **get some data right after connection** (So I would not need to call that `/ws-item/update/{itemId}` endpoint right after successfull connection?